# Using Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem to show convergence of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I stumbled upon this problem (its source is in Romanian and it will be redundant to link it here), and I got stuck halfway into the solution. The problem states:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1, -3\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x) = \ln(|x^2 +4x +3|)$, and $(x_{n})_{n \geq 1} $ be defined as $ x_n = f'(1) - f'(2)+\dots+f'(2n-1)-f'(2n).$ Show that $(x_{n})_{n \geq 1} $ converges.

Until now, I computed the derivative as $f'(x) = \frac{2x+4}{x^2+4x+3}$ for $x\geq 1$. The problem's hint is to show that the sequence is monotonic and bounded, therefore converging (by Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem).

The monotonicity is easily proven by computing $x_{n+1} -x_n$. Note that $$f'(x) = \frac{2x+4}{x^2+4x+3}= \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+3}.$$ Then, $$x_{n+1} -x_n =f'(2n+1)-f'(2n+2)= \frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+4}-\frac{1}{n+3} = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+3)(n+4)},$$ which is greater than $0$ for any $n\geq1$, and thus $x_n$ is strictly increasing.

The problem comes when I have to show the sequence is bounded.

Comment: Assuming your formula for xn is right, , your calculation for $x_n-x_{n+1 }$ is wrong, it is less than 0

Comment: It seems the series $\sum (x_{n+1}-x_{n})$ is convergent which implies $x_n$ is convergent.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc $\sum(x_{n+1}-x_{n})$ is the exact definition of $x_n$ in the non-recurrent form. Regardless, how would you prove it?

Comment: $x_{n+1} -x_n$ is not equal to $\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+3)(n+4)}$ but to $\frac1{(2n+2)(2n+3)} + \frac1{(2n+4)(2n+5)}.$ Anyway, it is $O(1/n^2)$ hence the series is convergent.

Comment: The domain of $f$ is not $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1, 3\}$ but $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1, -3\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spontaneously, I wouldn't follow the hint but simply notice that $x_n$ is the $2n$-th partial sum of a [convergent alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Alternating_series_test).

Comment: Therefore, $x_n\le f'(1).$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$0\le x_{n+1}-x_n={1\over 2n+2}+{1\over 2n+4}-{1\over 2n+3}-{1\over 2n+5}\\ ={1\over (2n+2)(2n+3)}+{1\over (2n+4)(2n+5)}\\ \le {2\over n(n+1)}={2\over n}-{2\over n+1}$$ Thus the series $\sum (x_{n+1}-x_n)$ is convergent by the comparison test.